# "Link all assemblies" causes my app to crash

Tags: ios, linker, xamarin.forms

When I set linker behavior to "Link all assemblies" my app crashes, unable to find what is causing this. Only thing I can get from device log is this

```
Error (169) / SpringBoard: SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Error (169) / SpringBoard: SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Error (18961) / securityd: secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found
Error (18961) / securityd: secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found
Error (19385) / amfid: SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Info (0) / kernel: xpcproxy[19394] Container: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/402654FC-0261-4DFA-AB0D-F35C3A0929F7 (sandbox)
Error (1) / com.apple.xpc.launchd: assertion failed: 13G36: launchd + 85529 [083E000D-4C31-3B98-A2C4-6FADB4D1940F]: 0x3
Warning (19394) / SthotraaniiOS: Found new TLS offset at 176
Error (19394) / SthotraaniiOS: nw_endpoint_create_address Changing endpoint address length from 28 to 16, too long for family AF_INET
Error (19394) / SthotraaniiOS: nw_endpoint_create_address Fixing endpoint address with non-zero sin_zero field
Warning (169) / SpringBoard: BSXPCMessage received error for message: Connection invalid
Warning (169) / SpringBoard: BSXPCMessage received error for message: Connection invalid
Warning (169) / SpringBoard: UNNotificationRegistrarConnectionListener connection invalidated
Warning (169) / SpringBoard: HW kbd: Failed to set (null) as keyboard focus
Warning (169) / SpringBoard: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.chirravuris.sthotraani[0x2155]' exited voluntarily.
```

Could someone help me find out how to enable "link all assemblies" without crashing the app